# Доставка контента в приложение через интернет

Tags: android

Приложение показывает пользователю список фильмов. При нажатии на элемент списка, запускается другое activity, где пользователь может прочитать большой текст-описание к этому фильму (контент). Я хочу сделать так, чтобы этот контент был доступен только при подключении к интернету, но если пользователь хочет читать текст оффлайн, то он должен нажать на значок "скачать" напротив элемента списка, и файл загрузится из интернета и потом пользователь сможет читать текст-описание оффлайн.

Я совершенно не знаю, как реализовать эту систему. Может быть есть какие-либо сайты или сервисы для этого? Или все гораздо проще?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы можете использовать BroadcastReceiver для отлавливания изменения состояния интернет соединение, для этого Вам нужно подписать ресивер на экшн android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE и при срабатывании метода onReceive() обновить состояние своего списка, например хранить булевое поле состояния интернета в адаптере списка и при отрисовке элемента списка проверять его значение

Comment: Дело в том, что я не знаю откуда загружать этот контент. Может нужно создавать сайт или еще что